# What kind of larva is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It has a body which is divided into three parts:

- The head, which is small, with a black, needle-like structure on the tip which I think is the mouth.
- The upper body, which has a pure white color that is softer than the lower body.
- The lower body, which is hard, has some blacks spots on the rear end with a yellow spot on the very tip and, compared to the upper part, has a clouded clear white color.

It moves very strongly when touched, but not that much.

My classmate found this when he opened a leaf from a small plant, thinking that it was a butterfly pupa because it was covered with a silk like cover but very thin to be compared to a butterfly cocoon.

Larva pictured here:

[image]

Comment: What about adding location?

Comment: That's going to be a moth. You can identify the wings forming, and which end will be the abdomen. You're upside down; the little black needle part is the eliminating end of the moth pupa. The head is at the end with multiple dots. When it is far enough along, you'll be able to make out everything: eyes, antennae, etc. They often encase themselves in silk (think silk moths caterpillars).

Comment: Location, and the plant it was found on may help.

Comment: +1 for the efforts in description. I agree with @anongoodnurse that you got the orientation wrong, though. What you see on the photo is the ventral face, with the head to the right. You can also guess the legs forming on the right part.